# Problem installing Box Sync 4 application on El Capitan

Tags: macos, install, dmg

I download the Box Sync .dmg, see the mounted installer, click on the installer, enter my password, and NOTHING happens.

I have tried this myriad different ways. I have restarted the laptop several times, to no avail. I am the only user and have admin rights. How do I fix this?

I know there was a different thread of the same title, but that was a case of not seeing the mounted installer and fixed in preferences. I can SEE the installer, I can interact with it. It does nothing.

Comment: Is it one particular DMG, or does this happen with lots of different DMG files? If it's one particular DMG could you tell us which one so we can try it?

Comment: Hi Alistair, It seems to just be the Box Sync .dmg at this point: https://sites.box.com/sync4/

Comment: To make sure it wasn't all .dmg's, I tried installing the latest version of Flash Player, which installed just fine. With Box Sync, the installer mounts on the desktop, I can double-click, enter my password, then nothing happens. I see no new application in the Apps folder. A search turns up nothing.

Comment: I've edited your question slightly as the problem appears to be specific to Box Sync. Hope you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short story:** drag and drop the Box Sync.app from the DMG file to your /Applications folder and run it from there. It takes a moment to present the login prompt but it does work from there.

**Long short** I tried the Box installer on my Mac and was getting the same issue as yourself. Watching in Activity Monitor, after I double-click on the Box Synx.app within the mounted DMG file it prompted for my password and then seconds later disappeared from Activity Monitor with no explanation.

I ran `fs_usage` to watch what the installer was doing and it showed that it was writing to a log file in /Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/Box/Box Sync/Box Sync-4.0.6974.log. Each time I tried to run the installer it wrote the following lines to the log and exits.

```
[36m2015-12-09 10:54:09.646 72816 INFO    MainThread           mac_self_updater      Mac self updater. user: 501, elevated user: 501, running from: /Volumes/Box Sync Installer/Box Sync.app[0m
[36m2015-12-09 10:54:09.646 72816 INFO    MainThread           mac_self_updater      installing into: /Applications/Box Sync.app[0m
[36m2015-12-09 10:54:09.648 72816 INFO    MainThread           mac_privileged_execut _get_installed_version: /Volumes/Box Sync Installer/Box Sync.app/Contents/Resources/com.box.sync.bootstrapper --version[0m
[32m2015-12-09 10:54:09.666 72816 DEBUG   MainThread           mac_privileged_execut Executable should be installed/updated. Current version 0, bundled version 2[0m
[36m2015-12-09 10:54:09.667 72816 INFO    MainThread           mac_privileged_execut Executing command /Volumes/Box Sync Installer/Box Sync.app/Contents/Resources/com.box.sync.bootstrapper with arguments [u'--install_sync', u'--sync_app_path', u'/Volumes/Box Sync Installer/Box Sync.app', u'--install_path', u'/Applications/Box Sync.app', u'--parent_process_id', u'72816'][0m
[36m2015-12-09 10:54:09.667 72816 INFO    MainThread           mac_privileged_execut Requesting create execute authorization ref[0m
[31m2015-12-09 10:54:23.938 72816 ERROR   MainThread           mac_bootstrapper      Failed to launch new sync app.  Error message: You can’t save the file “Box Sync” because the volume “Box Sync Installer” is read only.[0m
[31m2015-12-09 10:54:23.944 72816 ERROR   MainThread           mac_sync_app_delegate Unable to launch application via the bootstrapper.  Double click installation will fail silently![0m
```

For some reason it is trying to change one or more of the files within the DMG (perhaps just to change permissions), but it can't get write access within the read-only DMG so it silently fails.

Basically there is a bug in their software that needs to be fixed. In the meantime you can work around it by copying the application to a place where you it can modify the files.

I've left a message on their support forum. https://community.box.com/t5/Help-Forum/Mac-installer-fails-on-double-click/m-p/8641

Comment: I'd like to add that while using this technique worked and solved my issue it took about 15 seconds for the installer to show up after authenticating. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @KimtheConfused they have now updated that forum post to acknowledge the problem. They are working to fix it and they have reverted the installer on their website to a previous version. BTW if you're happy with this answer you can click the tick beside the answer to indicate you accept it.